# In Android studio, is there a short cut for using the static import?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I currently use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then select the "add static import" option. Would be nice if I could assign a short cut key to it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Key Promoter Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4455-key-promoter). It's simple and straightforward.